# Add onclick function to a href with a this parameter using Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, this, addition

I have a href like this

```
<a title="my title text" id="6" href="#" class="someclass" onclick="deleteRows(this.parentNode.parentNode)">X</a>
```

Now I want to add a new exactly the same href but I have no idea how to add onclick with 'this' paraeter.

Tried those 2 but non of it is working.

```
var a = document.createElement('a'); // create DIV element
    a.onclick = function() {
        (a.parentNode.parentNode);
    };
```

and

```
var a = document.createElement('a'); // create DIV element
    a.onclick = function() {
        (this.parentNode.parentNode);
    };
```

Searched google but did not faound anything.
How I should do it?

Comment: _"non of it is working"_ What does it do instead of what you expect? Also, did you forget to call `deleteRows` in those functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `deleteRows` inside your event listener:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.onclick = function() {
    deleteRows(this.parentNode.parentNode);
};
```